# magento 2 admin login page broken

Tags: magento2, admin

My Magento 2 admin login page has broken... its url rewrite problem. Also before this when it was working page and product were not loading & it is also not loading `js css` in back-end. Please check the image below . I have tried all possible solution but still getting this problem.

Comment: Have you done static content deploy. Also check your mod rewrite setting on server means apache/

Answer (score 1):

Try to static deploy - **php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy** in the magento root directory